# ASA database file data missing

Tags: powerbuilder, sybase-asa

I have a PowerBuilder app connecting to a ASA 8 database file via ODBC in location a. I then copy the same db file to location b, reconfigure ODBC to read the db file from location b, but now the data is gone.

Whats up ?

Is all the data stored in the .bd file or somewhere else? What could lead to the data of the same bd file being shown in location a but not in loc b ?

Thanks in advance
Alex

Comment: "data is gone" is a little vague. Could you be more specific? Do you get an error message? What is your system? Do you have UAC activated?

Comment: I have a database file a.db in folder location a with data in it. I take this file an copy it in location b. I remap the odbc to read the database file from new location b. Theoretically speaking both database files should contain the same set of data. But no... db file in location b is 'empty'. I renap the odbc profile to read back to location a and viola the user data is visible.

Comment: Is the "b" location is a system protected / privileged place like "program files"? Did you checked that the system did not make joke like storing the data into the VirtualStore of the user account?

Comment: The db files are in sepperate locations in a normal folder on the c drive. Both instances I log in as system default dba/sql

Comment: The tables and columns are visible. . Just that the user data is not

Comment: You are double-sure that it is the right database file that is read? The application does not use another datasource? Can you see the data with sybase-central after reconfiguration of the DSN? (There must be a Cartesian explanation :o)

Comment: Yes 100% sure. I have many instances where it does work with different db files. Just every now and again I have one where my mentioned problem is an issue. I have not tried sybase central.